# How to handle RAC binding with failed network signal in Reactive Cocoa

Tags: reactive-cocoa

In the following code,

```
RAC(photoModel, thumbnailData) = [self download:photoModel.thumbnailURL];
```

I bound the thumbnail of a model to a network signal, if it fails it should be retried, but RAC cannot be rebound. Should use side effect instead of binding or rebind it manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [`-retry:`](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/1a476a945c2e66838ea49227c0d01eaacd0b2ffd/ReactiveCocoaFramework/ReactiveCocoa/RACSignal+Operations.h#L600-L604) operator. If you apply it to the signal returned from the `-download` method, then any error sent by the signal will cause the download signal to retry.